# I have a problem in my split-screen game

Tags: game-engine

I have made my one scene single player and the other split-screen, the are both fps. For the single player scene I set a parent of cube to my character and made it look like the sky . In my split-screen I can't do that as one camera can see the other box when they enter. If I just add a box and not partner it, it looks like the sky is more of a wall with a sky on it and not a sky. i know you can stop objects from being rendered, but is there a way to set one of two cameras from seeing an object while the other can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a background scene for the skydome instead of a parent.

Comment: I have try that, almost every time the background was to big to make out, so I moved to the box insted as it was easier, but I will try it again because I use a panarama insted of a HDRI image.

Comment: Do split screen on the background scene too.

Comment: It has worked, but is still big and difficalt to make out, but for now it works